# What is a proper way to solve this inequation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is a proper way to solve this inequation?

$$(4/10)^n < 0.04$$

I can do this just with calculator but I don't know if it is a good way to do so.

**Edit:**
The answer should be an approximate natural number ($\ge 4$).

Comment: It's an inequation, not an equation.

Comment: @tommee You don't happen to know about induction do you? It's kind of overkill here, but it would be a super easy way to prove your inequality for all $n\geq 4$ without talking about increasing or decreasing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinc $n$ is an integer you can do that by hand, knowing you have a decreasing function of $n$:
$$\begin{matrix}n=&1&2&3&4\\\hline
f(n)=&4\cdot 10^{-1}& 16\cdot 10^{-2}& 6.4\cdot 10^{-2}&2.56\cdot 10^{-2}\end{matrix}$$

Hence $\Bigl(\dfrac{4}{10}\Bigr)^n<0.04\,\,$ for all $n\ge 4$.

Comment: I've known this way but I thought that maybe there is a more 'professional' way.

Comment: What's no professional? Not using more sophisticated tools? We don't require an exact solution, as though $n$ were a real number. We don't need a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: But what if n would turn out to be e.g. 120? It would be a lot of computations. In this case the @Alec's solution is better.

Comment: Of course, since it would be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln(*)$ is an increasing function we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^n<0.04=\frac{1}{25}=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2&\implies\ln\left[\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^n\right]<\ln\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)\\
&\implies n\ln\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)<-2\ln 5\\
&\implies n>\frac{2\ln 5}{\ln(5/2)}
\end{align*}

---

Since $\frac{4}{10}<1$, then $\frac{4}{10}$, $\frac{16}{100}$, $\frac{64}{1000}$, $\frac{256}{10000}$, $\frac{1024}{100000}$, $\ldots,\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^n,\ldots\quad$ is a decreasing sequence, it is the same that
$$0.4,\;0.16,\;0.064,\;0.0256,\;0.01024,\;\ldots,(0.4)^n$$ then we have $n=4$ is the least integer number such that $\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^n<0.04$.

Comment: You could equally write $$n< \frac{2\ln(5)}{\ln\left(\frac{5}{2} \right)}$$ if you are like me and tend to remove negatives when possible ;)

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that I need to result which is a natural number. The answer is >= 4 and WolframAlpha says that your result is approximately 3.51 so your answer is probably correct. Is it possible to estimate the result without scientific calculator (which is required to logarithms)?

Comment: @tommee - $\ln(5)$ is the number you need to raise $e$ to, to get 5. So obviously between 1 and 2. Then, you can estimate $\ln(5/2)$ by rewriting this as $\ln5 - \ln2$ and use the same kind of intuition.

Comment: It's a good way too, thank you.